# Node: child_process.js:427 throw new TypeError("This handle type can't be sent");

Tags: node.js, child-process

I am getting an error when using process.send in a child process, as in:

```
process.send(someObject, function() {
   ....
});
```

The child process is created as in:

```
 var child = require('child_process');
 var forkedProcess = child.fork(nodeScriptFile);
```

The error is:

```
child_process.js:427
           throw new TypeError("This handle type can't be sent");
                 ^
   TypeError: This handle type can't be sent
```

The programs works fine on one server. I tried to create a separate production server by copying all files and I started getting this error. Of course, there is a lot more to the programs, then the code shown above. 
I feel that i have overlooked some install or something trivial. I looked at child-process.js code and the error is triggered from this code:

```
  if (handle instanceof net.Socket) {
    message.type = 'net.Socket';
  } else if (handle instanceof net.Server) {
    message.type = 'net.Server';
  } else if (handle instanceof process.binding('tcp_wrap').TCP ||
             handle instanceof process.binding('pipe_wrap').Pipe) {
    message.type = 'net.Native';
  } else if (handle instanceof dgram.Socket) {
    message.type = 'dgram.Socket';
  } else if (handle instanceof process.binding('udp_wrap').UDP) {
    message.type = 'dgram.Native';
  } else {
    throw new TypeError("This handle type can't be sent");
  }
```

Spent considerable time... Please help!!!

Comment: Are you using the callback function to `process.send()`? I'm pretty sure that the error is caused by that.

Comment: @robertklep Yes, I am using a callback function to process send. However I was doing so on another server. After reading your comment, I checked with the Nodejs versions.  The one on which it is working is v4.4.3 and the on which it was not working was  v. .10 or something like that! I upgraded to v4.4.3 and it works fine.  If you post your comment as an answer, I will be happy to accept it as I suspect that in the older version there was no callback to process.send and it therefore interpreted the callback as the handle?Please clarify in the answer you post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In older version of Node (0.10 and perhaps 0.12 as well), `process.send()` was synchronous, so it didn't accept a callback function. However, it did accept an optional second argument, [`sendHandle`](https://nodejs.org/docs/v0.10.36/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle).

In your case, where you were using an older Node version, the error was thrown because your callback function argument wasn't a valid argument for `.send()` and therefore it fell through all the `handle instanceof ...` tests that you showed in your question.